# How to modify configuration by gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Example `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId propAppcationId
    }
}
```

My plugin:

```
public class AudioMaterialAppConstructorPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        Task constructAudioMaterialApp = project
                .getTasks()
                .create("constructAudioMaterialApp", ConstructAudioMaterialAppTask.class);
        project.getTasks().getByName("preBuild").dependsOn(constructAudioMaterialApp);
    }
}
```

My custom task:

```
public class ConstructAudioMaterialAppTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void constructAudioMaterialApp() {
        getProject().setProperty("propAppcationId", "demo.project.id");
    }

}
```

I want to change `applicationId` before `build task`. As you can see, I tried to do it via property, but it doesn't work. How can I manage this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because config is resolved during configuration phase and task is executed during execution phase (after).

You can add property in plugin apply method as an alternative. I think it should also work in task constructor, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks! I used plugin's `apply` method and it works: `@Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.setProperty("propAppcationId", "demo.project.id");
    }`